# Reporting tool(facility) with small size

Tags: c#, .net, windows, reporting-services

I am using .net with c#. If there is a requirement of giving facility of reporting. Report will be for chart. And report will be for information coming from datatable which will be created manually.

I tried with crystal report and it was done completely. But when user will download the full application, framework 2.0 will be installed and it is ok, but if we use crystal report then in the client machine whole crystal report will be installed in client machine what I don't want because it is with more size.So requirement for reporting is only for giving report for chart and for printing data for datatable.

Then what are other alternatives for crystal report which with my requirements can be satisfied and most important thing is size of that report facility should be as possible as small. Or if there is a reporting facility when we use it we have to just import the dll then that dlls should be of small size.So what are reporting tool which comes with as possible as small size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast report is the answer. It can be easy to make report with fast report. We have to just register the datatable and we can make report. The link is fast-report.com.

Answer (score 0):

For WPF / Silverlight / Windows Phone 7 I highly recommend Visifire : http://www.visifire.com/

 You can also view the source code :) I would hate distributing something I do not have the source code for in case I need it :)

Comment: Yes using an elementhost http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms